# WM_PAINT of a remote process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll-injection

I want to "intercept" the WM_PAINT msg of an other process chatBox.
the function: GetMessage(msg, hwnd, 0, 0) seems to be perfect but i'm not receiving any messages (I tryied as super user)
from now my C++ code find the good child windows and try to "getMessage",
What did I forget? I necessarily have to inject this code in a dll to my other process?

Comment: Do you really mean "remote" or it is just another process in the same computer?

Comment: yes on the same computer sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Message queues are per thread, so you cannot GetMessage for the other thread or process.

What you need is to install a window hook. See [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with WH_CALLWNDPROC hook type. Your dll will be loaded to all processes and intercept all window messages.

Then decide which messages/processes/windows you need to ignore and which to handle.

Comment: thanks but there is something i do wrong,
/* h is the HWND of the whanted windows */

     GetWindowThreadProcessId(h, &pid);
     if (!SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, (HOOKPROC)CallWndProc, NULL, pid))
        std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;

this ended with a failed

Comment: You need to move your CallWndProc to a separate DLL and pass a DLL handle to SetWindowsHookEx function.